# Google Script erases columns formulas after running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

CONTEXT

I have a script that I couldn't find it's origin now but that I've adapted it to my needs.
Within a google sheets, it searches for multiple conditions (If one column has one of multiple values: "payment not received", "payout_approved", etc **+** in state column is "PENDING" **+** a specific string of text is in another column - all in same row) and if they meet, it changes row status to ".PAID" (column with dropdown).
I've added a trigger and it works.

Several other columns have formulas on the first row after the table header and it seems that after the script runs it removes the formulas. All expected values can still be seen afterwards but formulas stop working (if I add more rows I can see the formulas stop working since they are array formulas/vlookup that fetch values from other sheets depending on what I add and also if I go the cell with the formula only the value is there, not the formula). It's the only script working at that specific time and I can check the changes history of the cells and see it matches the time the script ran).

WHAT I WOULD LIKE

I would like your help to:

- Adapt the script in order to work just after the dummy row, believing that that could solve the problem (I assume it would have something to do with the "i" being between something and the LR - Last Row: `for (var i=0;i<LR-1;i++){` )
- Identify any other problem on the script that may be the cause to the problem so I learn more about it and prevent to happen on future scripts

WHAT I HAVE

```
function PendingPayment_Status() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = "MASTER";
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
var Columns = 24;
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();

var refStatus = 'PENDING';
var refRequest = 'Payment not received. Please provide payment confirmation.';
var refCPstatus = 'payout_approved';
var refCPstatus2 = 'sent_to_finance';
var refCPstatus3 = 'special';
var refCPstatus4 ='fee_collected';

for (var i=0;i<LR-1;i++){
var cpstate = data[i+1][23];
var state = data[i+1][11];
var request = data[i+1][8];

// update the status to .PAID
if ((cpstate == refCPstatus && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus2 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus3 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus4 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest)){
  // request, sheet status and status match the reference data
  data[i+1][11] = ".PAID";
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Updated sheet status for row#"+(+i+1))
}  
}
 range.setValues(data);
 }
```

THank you in advance.

[TEST SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lvu-DnpammT75q2w_ijBmr4lrGGp1u9jqt_z6TUpIXg/edit?usp=sharing) - added afterwards

Answer (score 3):

#### Another possibility:

You can retrieve information about the range and create a new range with a combination of:

```js
range.getHeight()
range.getWidth()
sheet.getRange()
```

`sheet.getRange()` can use "A1" notation but it can also be called in the following way:

```js
sheet.getRange(1,1,5,10)
```

This gets range `"A1:E10"`. i.e. `.getRange(top left row, top left col, num of rows, num of cols)`

See below how this would be implemented in your script.

I also took the liberty of writing some parts of your code in a more concise way, though this is only my personal preference! :) For example, I made use of the `array.includes()` method to shorten your conditional statements.

```js
function PendingPayment_Status() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Columns = 5; // changed number of columns to fit my example
  var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // Always gets A1 as top left cell
  var rgHeight = range.getHeight()
  // you can also range.getWidth() if you want

  // Here you specify *2* as the top left row
  range = sheet.getRange(2,1,rgHeight - 1, Columns) // top left row, top left column, num of rows, num of columns
  
  var data = range.getValues();
 
  var refStatus = "PENDING"; // have to use double quotes here
  var refRequest = "Payment not received. Please provide payment confirmation.";
  
  var okCpStatuses = ["payout_approved", "sent_to_finance", "special", "fee_collected'"]
  
  for (var i=0; i<range.getHeight(); i++) {
    var cpstate = data[i][3]; // I changed index to fit my example
    var state = data[i][1]; // I changed index to fit my example
    var request = data[i][2]; // I changed index to fit my example
    
    // update the status to .PAID
    if (
         (state == refStatus && request == refRequest) &&
         ( okCpStatuses.includes(cpstate) )
    ) {
        // request, sheet status and status match the reference data
        data[i][1] = ".PAID"; // I changed the index to fit my example
    }
  }
 range.setValues(data);
  
}
```

I tested it with a local sheet, which is why the index numbers for the columns have been changed, but since I don't have your sheet, I can't test with yours.

Maybe next time you can provide your own example sheet and this would have been quicker :)

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Sorry for the delay but only now I could get back to this matter. I tried to adjust your script to my needs but it's not working well. I can't seem to update the column (it could be my mistake adjusting the values) and the formulas do remain but all the values  - as in the original script - become static values so the arrays cannot expand. I've created a test spreadsheet (added to original post) where I have a tab with the result after using your version. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- Your script gets the full data range of the sheet because it uses
  [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange):

  ```
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  ```
- Then you perform some operations to `data` and you set the values of the full data
  range back to the sheet:

  ```
  range.setValues(data);
  ```

As a result, all of your formulas are replaced by hard copy values.

---

### Solution:

- Instead, try to replace only the values of **column 11** which is the
  only column you want to alter:

  ```
   sheet.getRange(2,11,status_ar.length,1).setValues(status_ar)
  ```

  where `status_ar` has been initialized before the loop.

Try this:

```
function PendingPayment_Status() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = "MASTER";
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
var Columns = 24;
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();

var refStatus = 'PENDING';
var refRequest = 'Payment not received. Please provide payment confirmation.';
var refCPstatus = 'payout_approved';
var refCPstatus2 = 'sent_to_finance';
var refCPstatus3 = 'special';
var refCPstatus4 ='fee_collected';

var status_ar =[];  
  
for (var i=0;i<LR-1;i++){
var cpstate = data[i+1][23];
var state = data[i+1][11];
var request = data[i+1][8];

// update the status to .PAID
if ((cpstate == refCPstatus && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus2 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus3 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest) || (cpstate == refCPstatus4 && state == refStatus && request == refRequest)){

  status_ar.push([".PAID"])

}
  else {
    status_ar.push([""])
  }
}
 
 sheet.getRange(2,11,status_ar.length,status_ar[0].length).setValues(status_ar);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but only now I could get back to this matter. I tried to adjust your script to my needs. The formulas/arrays remain, values don't become static, but I'm having some troubles leaving the values in STATUS column as is if the row does not meet the conditions. I've added a test spreadsheet to original post

Comment: any thoughts on this problem? I've been testing but everytime i change the else condition, the changes go to the incorrect rows